# XElement.Load() and "undeclared prefix" exception

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to load xml file using Xelement.Load() method and in case of some files, I get *"ditaarch" is an undeclared prefix* exception. The content of such troublesome xml's are similar to this simplified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<concept ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.3">
<title>Test Title</title>
<menucascade>
    <uicontrol>text</uicontrol>
    <uicontrol/>
</menucascade>
</concept>
```

I've tried to follow suggestions to manually add or ignore "ditaarch" namespace using xml namespace manager:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\test\example.xml"))
{
    NameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
    nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("ditaarch", "");
    XmlParserContext parserContext = new XmlParserContext(null, nameSpaceManager, null, XmlSpace.None);
              
    XElement elem = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```

But it leads to same exception as before. Most probably the solution is trivial but I just can't see it :(

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your use case? How large is data you'd be processing?

Comment: The reason you get the error is because the namespace with prefix `ditaarch` isn't defined anywhere in your XML (usually it can be found in the root node, in this case `<concept>`). So basically your XML is invalid.

Comment: @user94614 - this is just a part of tool used to check if xml files does not include any empty elements after they get back from translation, each batch have around 1~3k of xml files.

Comment: @silkfire - yes, I'm aware that lack of definition make such file "not well formed" but unfortunately I can't do anything about it since xml's I'm working on cannot have their structure modified in any way, except for the strings inside some of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented markup is not namespace well-formed XML so I don't think XElement or XDocument is an option as it doesn't support colons in names. You can parse it with a legacy `new XmlTextReader("foo.xml") { Namespaces = false }` however.

And you could use `XmlDocument` instead of `XDocument` or `XElement` and check for any empty elements with e.g.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlReader xr = new XmlTextReader("example.xml") { Namespaces = false })
        {
            doc.Load(xr);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Number of empty elements: {0}", doc.SelectNodes("//*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]").Count);
```

Comment: Kudos to you Sir. Following your suggestion while using [this custom class](https://github.com/icsharpcode/WpfDesigner/blob/5a994b0ff55b9e8f5c41c4573a4e970406ed2fcd/WpfDesign.XamlDom/Project/PositionXmlDocument.cs) I was able to modify my code to return empty elements with line and position information, so travelling back in time to `XmlDocument` did not hurt me that much :)
Edit - formatting.